# Building nested lambda expression as variable recursively, strange stackoverflow in specific situation. Unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, lambda, stack-overflow

First, some example code.

I've made the following abstraction of my problem which you can put in linqpad.

```
Func<int, int> recursiveSomethingIntegers(int b){
    if(b == 1){
        return x => x * x;
    }
    if(b == 2){
        return x => x * x + 1;
    }
    var intArray = new int[]{1, 2};
    Func<int, int> lExpression = null;
    Func<int, int> someOtherExpression = null;
    if(b == 3){
        foreach(var a in intArray){
            if(lExpression == null){
                Console.WriteLine("Called only once");
                lExpression = recursiveSomethingIntegers(a);
                continue;
            }
            else{
                Console.WriteLine("Also called only once");

                // This statement leads to the error
                lExpression = x => lExpression(a) + 2;
                // This one, which has the same initialization doesn't.
                someOtherExpression = x => lExpression(a) + 2;
                // Comment out either one of the above
            }
        }
    }
    return someOtherExpression ?? lExpression;
}

var someExpression = recursiveSomethingIntegers(3);

Console.WriteLine(someExpression(3));
```

As you can see, the code is completely meaningless. Still, I believe the issue that arises by reusing the variable is not intentional design.

While debugging this in Visual Studio, it gives me a "access violation" error, not an exception, at least in my real code.

If I run it normally, it gives a StackOverflowException instead.

When the lambda is being executed in `Console.WriteLine(someExpression(3));`
It gets stuck on `lExpression = x => lExpression(a) + 2;` and keeps adding to the stack, obviously resulting in a stackoverflow. 
Meanwhile using another variable it's fine.

If you'd do this with normal variable instead of lambda expressions, it's fine.

I my use case I need to use the same variable name again because my foreach loop should be able to run an arbitrary amount of cycles.

My question would be if this actually is unintentional C#/Compiler/Runtime behavior? Because to me, it seems like it violates the design of the language.

EDIT: I'm looking more into the debugger I think that `lExpression = x => lExpression(a) + 2;` refined BOTH `lExpression` in the initialization as the first `lExpression`.

That'd be like `x = x + 1` would redefine BOTH `x`s as the result of `x + 1`, which doesn't make ANY sense.

EDIT2: A way around this:
Instead of

```
lExpression = x => lExpression(a) + 2;
```

Do:

```
var clonedExpression = lExpression.Clone() as Func<int, int>;
lExpression = x => clonedExpression(a) + 2;
```

I don't fully understand why this works though.

Another example if you'd prefer to use a Visual studio project to try it out:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        public Program()
        {
            var someExpression = recursiveSomethingIntegers(3);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(someExpression(3));
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p = new Program();
        }

        Func<int, int> recursiveSomethingIntegers(int b)
        {
            if (b == 1)
            {
                return x => x * x;
            }
            if (b == 2)
            {
                return x => x * x + 1;
            }
            var intArray = new int[] { 1, 2 };
            Func<int, int> lExpression = null;
            Func<int, int> someOtherExpression = null;
            if (b == 3)
            {
                foreach (var a in intArray)
                {
                    if (lExpression == null)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Called only once");
                        lExpression = recursiveSomethingIntegers(a);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Also called only once");

                        // This statement leads to the error
                        lExpression = x => lExpression(a) + 2;
                        // This one, which has the same initialization, doesn't.
                        someOtherExpression = x => lExpression(a) + 2;
                        // Comment out either one of the above, don't leave both uncommented
                    }
                }
            }
            return someOtherExpression ?? lExpression;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first statement (`lExpression = x => lExpression(a) + 2`) is assigning a new value to `lExpression`, hence when the function eventually invoked it calls itself endlessly. Your second statement (`someOtherExpression = x => lExpression(a) + 2`) doesn't change the value of `lExpression` hence when called, proceeds as expected.

Comment: @haim Yes, but why is the actual value of the second `lExpression` changed. By that logic `x = x + 1` would also call itself endlessly. I want the second `lExpression` to be resolved to the value of the variable, which is one of the first 2 lambda expressions at the top of the program.

Comment: It would only calls itself endlessly if you're changing the value of `lExpression`, because the function that you `return` from `recursiveSomethingIntegers()` is still referencing that `lExpression` variable (using "capturing").

Comment: @bassfader Would there be a way to not have it overwrite the original `lExpression` delegate and keep the original there?

Comment: @bassfader No. The created delegate is "capturing" `lExpression`, hence once invoked would reference the (now-modified) `lExpression`. Try and see.

Comment: @haim770 you're right, my bad, I confused something here -.-

Comment: I found a way to go around this.
instead of `lExpression = x => lExpression(a) + 2;`.
Do `var clonedExpression = lExpression.Clone() as Func<int, int>;` and then `lExpression = x => clonedExpression(a) + 2;`. Which looks really stupid but it works.